# Facebook blocking login inside WebViews

Tags: flutter, facebook, webview, flutter-inappwebview

We are using the [Flutter InAppWebView Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/4.0.0+4) for user registration flow and we have a step where users have to sign in to their Facebook account for an Instagram connection.

Recently we Facebook published a blog post that they are [deprecating support for FB Login authentication on Android embedded browsers](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/06/28/deprecating-support-fb-login-authentication-android-embedded-browsers/), but some users, including us, experienced the issue with sign-in into Facebook inside WebViews on iOS:

[image]

Has anyone experience the same issue and found a workaround?

Would be grateful for the help on how to resolve it.

Comment: In my organization the app developers are using a Chrome Tab or SafariTab rather than embedded webview. They get the access_token through the login there.

Comment: you should use this plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth) for facebook authentication, not a web view.